# i have two drop downs i need to select a value from both at a time

Tags: selenium-webdriver

here i have two drop downs one is "select Driver" and another one is "Select Car" ,i need to select a value from both drop downs at a time..

```
      this is for "select Driver" drop down

     new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h1[contains(., 'Dashboard')]")));
     driver.get("https://ecabportal.azurewebsites.net/addassignVechile");
     new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='load']")));
     new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span.select2-selection__rendered"))).click();
     new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[contains(., 'Malveena')]"))).click();

    this is for "Select Car" drop down

     new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h1[contains(., 'Dashboard')]")));
     driver.get("https://ecabportal.azurewebsites.net/addassignVechile");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='load']")));
     new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span.select2-selection__rendered"))).click();
     new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[contains(., 'X5')]"))).click();
```

"select driver" dropdown is working but i got error in console like "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //h1[contains(., 'Dashboard')] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)"

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//h1[contains(., 'Dashboard')]"}

Comment: help me  anyone please

Answer (score 0):

There are two exceptions in this case 1) TimeOutException and 2) NoSuchElementException. In your case the path what you are using in explicitwait is not finding any element even after 20 seconds. Die to thos reason, selenium unable to find an element and its gets failed.
You can check your path once in application manually as it is not identifying any element with the provided.

Coming to the exceptions, TimeOutException will raise when we use explicitWait and when the given time is expired before satisfying the mentioned condition. You can make sure your path that will resolve your issue..